# merge output files after reduce phase

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

In mapreduce each reduce task write its output to a file named *part-r-nnnnn* where *nnnnn* is a partition ID associated with the reduce task. Does *map/reduce* merge these files? If yes, how?

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Instead of doing the file merging on your own, you can delegate the entire merging of the reduce output files by calling:

```
hadoop fs -getmerge /output/dir/on/hdfs/ /desired/local/output/file.txt
```

**Note** This combines the HDFS files locally. Make sure you have enough disk space before running

Comment: is there a way to do this but on the dfs? I mean I want to merge them into a single file on the dfs?

Comment: It doesn't seem to work with the dfs, the merged file gets written to the local file system. Of course you could just write it back, but seems wasteful.

Comment: NB: this isn't safe with non-text files. `getMerge` does a simple concatenation of files, which with something like a SequenceFile will not give a sane output.

Comment: This does not work with HDFS as the destination which is what is intended.

Comment: getmerge brings the data from hdfs to local.

Comment: If in dfs, you can merger txt or csv files: $ hadoop fs -cat /folder_with_files/* | hadoop fs -put - /output_folder/outputFile.dat

Comment: This doesn't work for the canonical Hadoop case of part*.gz files. The simple concat function is only meant for simple text files

Comment: Yes, you can merge files in hdfs directly without getting them in local. Follow this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/31188767/4401399

Answer (score 28):

No, these files are not merged by Hadoop. The number of files you get is the same as the number of reduce tasks.

If you need that as input for a next job then don't worry about having separate files. Simply specify the entire directory as input for the next job.

If you do need the data outside of the cluster then I usually merge them at the receiving end when pulling the data off the cluster.

I.e. something like this:

```
hadoop fs -cat /some/where/on/hdfs/job-output/part-r-* > TheCombinedResultOfTheJob.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer buf in config file of map/reduce (*mapred-default.xml*) there is an attribute named *io.sort.factor*, what does it used for???

Comment: The io.sort.factor has to do with the processing BETWEEN the map and the reduce step. Not the output of the reduce.

Comment: how do you know the order in which part-r-* file will be merged is the right one ?

Comment: @Razvan: The order should not matter. If it does matter then you have an algorithm that doesn't scale and you apparently have assumptions regarding which Reducer has done which part of the work.  So if that happens you have a problem of a different kind.

Comment: @NielsBasjes: It is better to use "hadoop fs -getmerge" instead of "hadoop fs -cat"

Answer (score 8):

That's the function you can use to Merge Files in HDFS

```
public boolean getMergeInHdfs(String src, String dest) throws IllegalArgumentException, IOException {
    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(config);
    Path srcPath = new Path(src);
    Path dstPath = new Path(dest);

    // Check if the path already exists
    if (!(fs.exists(srcPath))) {
        logger.info("Path " + src + " does not exists!");
        return false;
    }

    if (!(fs.exists(dstPath))) {
        logger.info("Path " + dest + " does not exists!");
        return false;
    }
    return FileUtil.copyMerge(fs, srcPath, fs, dstPath, false, config, null);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

For text files only and HDFS as both the source and destination, use the below command:

`hadoop fs -cat /input_hdfs_dir/* | hadoop fs -put - /output_hdfs_file`

This will concatenate all the files in `input_hdfs_dir` and will write the output back to HDFS at `output_hdfs_file`. Do keep in mind that all the data will be brought back to the local system and then again uploaded to hdfs, although no temporary files are created and this happens on the fly using UNIX pe.

Also, this won't work with non-text files such as Avro, ORC etc.

For binary files, you could do something like this (if you have Hive tables mapped on the directories):

`insert overwrite table tbl select * from tbl`

Depending on your configuration, this could also create more than files. To create a single file, either set the number of reducers to 1 explicitly using `mapreduce.job.reduces=1` or set the hive property as `hive.merge.mapredfiles=true`.

Comment: With this solution also be aware of the possible input getting into the final destination from stdin. Namely, I came across a situation when in HA enabled cluster there is a warning message when one of the nodes are in standby mode. In that situation my output contained that otherwise innocent warning messages. [link](https://s.apache.org/sbnn-error)

Answer (score 4):

The part-r-nnnnn files are generated after the reduce phase designated by 'r' in between. Now the fact is if you have one reducer running, you will have an output file like part-r-00000. If the number of reducers are 2 then you're going to have part-r-00000 and part-r-00001 and so on. Look, if the output file is too large to fit into the machine memory since the hadoop framework has been designed to run on **Commodity Machines**, then the file gets splitted. As per the MRv1, you have a limit of 20 reducers to work on your logic. You may have more but the same needs to be customised in the configuration files **mapred-site.xml**.
Talking about your question; you may either use getmerge or you may set the number of reducers to 1 by embedding the following statement to the driver code

```
job.setNumReduceTasks(1);
```

Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 3):

You can run an additional map/reduce task, where map and reduce don't change the data, and partitioner assigns all data to a single reducer.

Comment: Not if you need to merge more data than the local machine can handle

Answer (score 1):

Besides my previous answer I have one more answer for you which I was trying few minutes ago. 
You may use ***CustomOutputFormat*** which looks like the code given below

```
public class VictorOutputFormat extends FileOutputFormat<StudentKey,PassValue> {

    @Override
    public RecordWriter<StudentKey,PassValue> getRecordWriter(
            TaskAttemptContext tac) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        //step 1: GET THE CURRENT PATH
        Path currPath=FileOutputFormat.getOutputPath(tac);

        //Create the full path
        Path fullPath=new Path(currPath,"Aniruddha.txt");

        //create the file in the file system
        FileSystem fs=currPath.getFileSystem(tac.getConfiguration());
        FSDataOutputStream fileOut=fs.create(fullPath,tac);
        return new VictorRecordWriter(fileOut);
    }

}
```

Just, have a look at the fourth line from the last. I have used my own name as the output file name and I have tested the program with 15 reducers. Still the File remains the same. So getting a single out file instead of two or more is possible yet to be very clear the size of the output file must not exceed the size of the primary memory i.e. the output file must fit into the memory of the commodity machine else there might be a problem with the output file split.
Thanks!!

Comment: getmerge can solve your purpose but that's an alternative. but that's useful

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a pig script like this one for merging partition files:

```
stuff = load "/path/to/dir/*"

store stuff into "/path/to/mergedir"
```

Answer (score 0):

If the files have header, you can get rid of it of by doing this:

```
hadoop fs -cat /path/to/hdfs/job-output/part-* | grep -v "header" > output.csv
```

then add the header manually for output.csv

Answer (score 0):

> . Does map/reduce merge these files?

No. It does not merge.

You can use [IdentityReducer](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/IdentityReducer.html) to achieve your goal.

> Performs no reduction, writing all input values directly to the output.

```
public void reduce(K key,
                   Iterator<V> values,
                   OutputCollector<K,V> output,
                   Reporter reporter)
            throws IOException
```

> Writes all keys and values directly to output.

Have a look at related SE posts:

[hadoop: difference between 0 reducer and identity reducer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10630447/hadoop-difference-between-0-reducer-and-identity-reducer)