# Combine output files of MapReduce job

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming, elastic-map-reduce

I have written a Mapper and Reducer in Python and have executed it successfully on Amazon's Elastic MapReduce(EMR) using Hadoop Streaming.

The final result folder contains the output in three different files part-00000, part-00001 and part-00002. But I need the output as one single file. Is there a way I can do that?

Here is my code for the Mapper:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.strip()
    words = line.split()
    for word in words:
        print '%s\t%s' % (word, 1)
```

And here is my code for the Reducer

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from operator import itemgetter
import sys

current_word = None
current_count = 0
word = None
max_count=0

for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.strip()
    word, count = line.split('\t', 1)

    try:
        count = int(count)
    except ValueError:
        continue

if current_word == word:
    current_count += count
else:
    if current_word:
        # write result to STDOUT
            if current_word[0] != '@':
                print '%s\t%d' % (current_word, current_count)
                if count > max_count:
                    max_count = count
    current_count = count
    current_word = word

if current_word == word:
    print '%s\t%s' % (current_word, current_count)
```

I need the output of this as one single file.

Comment: Can't you just open the three files and concatenate them into a single output file?

Comment: That is what I have been doing. But I would like it if I can get a single output file after the Reduce phase.

Comment: Can't you just do (*Linux/UNIX*): ``cat part-00000 part-00001 part-00002 > output``?

Comment: Thanks James. That's one way. But I can't get EMR itself to spit it out as one single part file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [merge output files after reduce phase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700068/merge-output-files-after-reduce-phase)

Answer (score 1):

A really simple way of doing this (*assuming a Linux/UNIX sytem*):

```
$ cat part-00000 part-00001 part-00002 > output
```

Comment: Or even better, `cat part-* > output`

Comment: I thought it would be better to be more explicit and not assume they were all called ``part-*`` :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a [single reduce](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HowManyMapsAndReduces) for small datasets/processing or use the [getmerge](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.19.1/hdfs_shell.html#getmerge) option on the output files of the job.

Comment: But the job itself is running on Elastic MapReduce. What then?

Comment: EMR or not, will support the options mentioned in the response.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to the above problem was to execute the following hdfs command:

```
hadoop fs -getmerge /hdfs/path local_file
```

where */hdfs/path* is a path containing all the parts (part-*****) of a job output.
The -getmerge option of the hadoop fs, will merge all of the job output into a single file on our local file system.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem lately, actually combiner should do this task but I couldn't implement somehow. What did I do is;

1. step1: mapper1.py reducer1.py

   input: s3://../data/

   output s3://..../small_output/
2. step2: mapper2.py reducer2.py

   input s3://../data/

   output: s3://..../output2/
3. step3: mapper3.py reducer3.py

   input: s3://../output2/

   output: s3://..../final_output/

I assume that we need output of step1 as a single file at the step3.

At the top of mapper2.py, there is this code;

```
if not os.path.isfile('/tmp/s3_sync_flag'):
    os.system('touch /tmp/s3_sync_flag')
    [download files to /tmp/output/]
    os.system('cat /tmp/output/part* > /tmp/output/all')
```

if block, checks against multiple mapper execution.