# Produce single output from Pig Script using Filter

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I have a simple PIG script that uses only the `FILTER` command in it.  It looks something like this ...

```
--sample_script.pig
some_data = load './a_file' as (col1:chararray, col2:chararray);
contains_ = filter some_data by (col2 == '1') OR (col2 == '2');
store contains_ into './a_new_file';
```

When I run this script it outputs a folder `a_new_file` with 3 files in it `part-m-00000`, `part-m-00001` and `_SUCCESS`.  From what I can gather, the way I have written my script doesn't require a reduce phase.  Is there a different way to write this so this script will output only one file?

Thanks.

Comment: Is it required that you not have a reduce phase ?, i mean if you can force your data through a single reducer it should do the job for you. Else you can override the inputformat to be non splittable (which would mean you run a single mapper). Else some kind of post processing to concat the files.

Comment: possible duplicate of [merge output files after reduce phase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700068/merge-output-files-after-reduce-phase)

Comment: @ WinnieNicklaus I believe you are correct.  I was hoping to modify my script but running the extra command from [merge output files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700068/merge-output-files-after-reduce-phase) works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set number of reducers in the script itself

```
--sample_script.pig
set default_parallel 1;
some_data = load './a_file' as (col1:chararray, col2:chararray);
contains_ = filter some_data by (col2 == '1') OR (col2 == '2');
store contains_ into './a_new_file';
```

OR

You can combine [small files](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/perf.html#combine-files)

Comment: I'm still getting multiple files.

Comment: Did u tried combining small files?
fs -getmerge  <Pig output file> <local file>

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PARALLEL 1` for filter alone in the below way

```
contains = filter some_data by (col2 == '1') OR (col2 == '2') PARALLEL 1;
```

this will creates only one part file