# How to create single file while using sqoop import with multiple mappers

Tags: hive, sqoop

I want to import data from Mysql using sqoop import but my requirement is i want to use 4 mappers but it should create only one file in hdfs target directory is there is any way to do this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [merge output files after reduce phase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700068/merge-output-files-after-reduce-phase)

Answer (score 2):

**No.** there is no option in sqoop to re-partition files into 1 file.

*I don't think this should be a headache of sqoop.*

You can do it easily using [**getmerge**](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#getmerge) feature of hadoop. Example:

```
hadoop fs -getmerge /sqoop/target-dir/ /desired/local/output/file.txt
```

Here

- `/sqoop/target-dir` is the `target-dir` of your sqoop command *(directory containing all the part files)*.
- `desired/local/output/file.txt` is the combined single file.

Answer (score 0):

you can use below sqoop command..!!

Suppose database name is `prateekDB` and table name is `Emp`...!!

```sh
sqoop import  --connect "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/prateekDB"  --username=root \
--password=data  --table Emp  --target-dir /SqoopImport  --split-by empno
```

Comment: You can improve your answer by formatting its code block.

Answer (score -1):

Add this option to sqoop

```
--num-mappers 1
```

the sqoop log shows:

```
Job Counters 
    Launched map tasks=1
    Other local map tasks=1
```

and finally on hdfs ONE file is created.