# how Merging File from Local with File HDFS?

Tags: scala, hadoop

i would like merging from local file from `/opt/one.txt` with file at my hdfs `hdfs://localhost:54310/dummy/two.txt`.

contains at **one.txt** : `f,g,h` 
contains at **two.txt** : `2424244r`

my code :

```
val cfg = new Configuration()
    cfg.addResource(new Path("/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml"))
    cfg.addResource(new Path("/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/hdfs-site.xml"))
    cfg.addResource(new Path("/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/mapred-site.xml"))

    try
    {
      val srcPath = "/opt/one.txt"
      val dstPath = "/dumCBF/two.txt"

      val srcFS = FileSystem.get(URI.create(srcPath), cfg)
      val dstFS = FileSystem.get(URI.create(dstPath), cfg)

      FileUtil.copyMerge(srcFS,
        new Path(srcPath),
        dstFS,
        new Path(dstPath),
        true,
        cfg,
        null)

      println("end proses")
    }

    catch
    {
      case m:Exception => m.printStackTrace()
      case k:Throwable => k.printStackTrace()
    }
```

i was following tutorial from : http://deploymentzone.com/2015/01/30/spark-and-merged-csv-files/

and it's not working at all, error would below this :

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: /opt/one.txt
```

i dont why, sounds of error like that? BTW the file **one.txt** is exist

and then, im add some code to check exist file :

```
if(new File(srcPath).exists()) println("file is exist")
```

any idea or references? thanks!

EDIT 1,2 : typo extensions

Comment: Can you try `file:///opt/one.txt`, since its available in local file system.

Comment: hello mr. @Shankar yes, its worked. but now, back to topic about merging. it wouldn't merge at all, and without error anything :(. any idea why?

Comment: Before merging your files, you need to copy the local file to HDFS, then you can merge.

Comment: file two.txt i was upload to hdfs, should i upload too one.txt?

Comment: you dont have to copy the two.txt, because that's what you are going to create as output file, basically this command is used to merge multiple partitioned files to single file. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700068/merge-output-files-after-reduce-phase and http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil

Comment: ok thank you, mr @Shankar its works now. hehehe, GBU!