# Save and append a file in HDFS using PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, hdfs

I have a data frame in PySpark called `df`. I have registered this `df` as a `temptable` like below.

```py
df.registerTempTable('mytempTable')

date=datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Now from this temp table I will get certain values, like max_id of a column `id`

```py
min_id = sqlContext.sql("select nvl(min(id),0) as minval from mytempTable").collect()[0].asDict()['minval']

max_id = sqlContext.sql("select nvl(max(id),0) as maxval from mytempTable").collect()[0].asDict()['maxval']
```

Now I will collect all these values like below.

```py
test = ("{},{},{}".format(date,min_id,max_id))
```

I found that `test` is not a `data frame` but it is a `str` string

```py
>>> type(test)
<type 'str'>
```

Now I want save this `test` as a file in `HDFS`. I would also like to append data to the same file in `hdfs`.

How can I do that using PySpark?

FYI I am using Spark 1.6 and don't have access to Databricks `spark-csv` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, you'll just need to concat your data with `concat_ws` and right it as a text:

```py
query = """select concat_ws(',', date, nvl(min(id), 0), nvl(max(id), 0))
from mytempTable"""

sqlContext.sql(query).write("text").mode("append").save("/tmp/fooo")
```

Or even a better alternative :

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

(sqlContext
    .table("myTempTable")
    .select(f.concat_ws(",", f.first(f.lit(date)), f.min("id"), f.max("id")))
    .coalesce(1)
    .write.format("text").mode("append").save("/tmp/fooo"))
```

Comment: this appends to the same directory /tmp/fooo is a directory path and not a file

Comment: there is no append to the same file thing with hadoop/spark

Comment: I believe there is the option using `hdfs dfs -appendToFile`

Comment: it uses the hdfs merge api but isn't available in spark. You can always use it afterwards with hadoop

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700068/merge-output-files-after-reduce-phase

Comment: No module error means that the library isn't available. I'm not sure I can be much help if you don't post a question with what you are trying to do and the error stack message.

Comment: I noticed that in your answer, the first option doesn't work

Comment: what do you mean ?

Comment: in this `query = """select concat_ws(',', date, nvl(min(id), 0), nvl(max(id), 0))
from mytempTable"""` date is not in the `temptable`. According  `OP` it is in the script

Comment: Are you sure we are reading the same question ? Is this a practical joke ?