# Save a file in HDFS from Pyspark

Tags: hadoop, pyspark, hdfs, apache-spark-sql

I have an empty table in `Hive` I mean there are no records in that table.

Using this empty table I have created a `data frame` in `pyspark`

```
df = sqlContext.table("testing.123_test")
```

I have registered this `data frame` as an temp table in

```
df.registerTempTable('mytempTable')

date=datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

In this table I have column called `id`.

Now I want to query the temp table like below

```
min_id = sqlContext.sql("select nvl(min(id),0) as minval from mytempTable").collect()[0].asDict()['minval']

max_id = sqlContext.sql("select nvl(max(id),0) as maxval from mytempTable").collect()[0].asDict()['maxval']
```

Now I want to save `date`, `min_id` and `max_id` into a file in `HDFS`

I have done like below:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

(sqlContext.table("myTempTable").select(f.concat_ws(",", f.first(f.lit(date)), f.min("id"), f.max("id"))).coalesce(1).write.format("text").mode("append").save("/tmp/fooo"))
```

Now when I check the file in `HDFS` it show all NULL values.

The file output in `HDFS` is below.

```
NULL,NULL,NULL
```

What I want is

```
Date,0,0
```

`Here date is the current timestamp`

How can I achieve what I want.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do here. Why read an empty table and then write `Date,0,0` to HDFS. Could you please elaborate a bit more?

Comment: @philantrovert Here I am trying to save the data of some tables in directory in `HDFS` I am able to do this if the table has records, but if the table is empty then I am facing the above scenario

Comment: It's funny. I know that code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/44315328/3415409

Comment: empty tables shouldn't be persisted. You just need to check count of the dataframe. So I honestly don't see what you are trying to do here

Comment: @eliasah What you said is correct but this table might have data when I run this script next time. So if we have empty tables it should right to `HDFS` file like my requirement

Answer (score 0):

This is in scala but you should be easily able to replicate it to Python.
The function you need here is [`na.fill`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameNaFunctions.fill) function. And you'll have to replace Scala Maps with Python Dictionaries in the below code:

This is what your DF looks like:

```
scala> nullDF.show
+----+----+----+
|date|   x|   y|
+----+----+----+
|null|null|null|
+----+----+----+

// You have already done this using Python's datetime functions
val format = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss")
val curr_timestamp = format.format(new java.util.Date())

//Use na fill to replace null values
//Column names as keys in map
//And values are what you want to replace NULL with

val df = nullDF.na.fill(scala.collection.immutable.Map(
         "date" -> ) ,
         "x" -> "0" ,
         "y" -> "0" ) )
```

This should give you

```
+-------------------+---+---+
|               date|  x|  y|
+-------------------+---+---+
|10/06/2017 12:10:20|  0|  0|
+-------------------+---+---+
```